# Magento joining two tables with different columns

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

i have to modify an adminhtml section for stock alerts. normally for a single product there's a retrieve of registered customer which have subscribed to alerts by this function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $websiteId = 0;
    if ($store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getWebsiteId();
    }
    $collection = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
        ->getCustomerCollection()
        ->join($productId, $websiteId);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

this (for what i  have understand) make a query on the table product_alert_stock which has the following columns:

```
alert_stock_id, customer_id, product_id, website_id, add_date, send_date, send_count, status
```

and then join it with the customer table to retriev customers names.

Well we have created a similar table for guest users (not registered), product_alert_stock_guest, with the following colums:

```
alert_stock_id, guest_email, product_id, website_id, add_date, send_date, send_count, status
```

as you can see the difference is the column guest_email which replace customer_id. is it possible to join (or do something similar) these two tables and then display it on the same grid?

thanx

Luca

---

@JakeTheFish
at the end I didn't do a join, but i retrieved guest stock alert objects in a similar of the regular stock alert, i set email field by setData('email', $item->getData('email')), and then i added them to $collection by addItem. I have an error:
Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Attempt to add add an invalid object')
when i do a log on regular stock alert items, i have a lot of information: http://pastebin.com/z7NpNJrH
instead with a custom guest stock alert items, i have this: http://pastebin.com/KKcTeQEH
so the problem is that i need a Mage_Customer_Model_Customer instance for the add. i could create one but:

1) i can fill attributes of that instance with normal methods as setField (i'm looking at the API right now and i dont see anything like that)

2) even if i can fill attributes, what happens if i set blank fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento provides such methods as:

```
joinAttribute
joinField
joinTable
```

But joined tables should have some similar id.

Based on these 2 links [1](http://webdevbyjoss.blogspot.com/2011/03/merge-two-collections-in-magento.html) and [2](http://groups.google.com/group/magento-devel/browse_thread/thread/e7ebc2da25755731)

Try something like this:

```
$selectFoo = Mage::getResourceModel('model/foo')->getSelect();
$selectBar= Mage::getResourceModel('model/bar')->getSelect();
$mergedFooBar = $selectFoo->union(array($selectBar));
```

OR you can add element to collection:

```
$collection->addItem($item);
```

BUT, You have 2 different classes and I don't want how they will merge in a single collection, I suppose if you want to unite 2 different entities, you should make those 2 subclass some third class, which negotiates difference between e-mail and customer_id.

Comment: tnx for your reply. I think the best solution is to join the two tables since they differ only for one column. the point is that if i perform this join, and then i do another join with the customer table, what are the side efftect on entries with customer_id...?

Comment: The thing is, that your guest_email is not connected with any customer_id. So if there will be any effect then it will be on entries where you don't have customer_id at all. I suggest you to have some third class which negotiates difference between guest_email and customer_id. Meaning that this will be some another model where you have something like "loadProperModel" and your model will have some field like "Customer identifier" where customerEmail or customerName will be. Something like this.

Comment: at the end I didn't do a join, but i retrieved guest stock alert objects in a similar of the regular stock alert, i set email field by setData('email', $item->getData('email')), and then i added them to $collection by addItem. I have an error: 'Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Attempt to add an invalid object')'